Help in identifying the font
Please help me identify the font in the image. The text seems to be Garamond, but I need to know what math font is used.
Thanks in advance.


https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Your example looks reasonably similar to the Garamond math fonts from mathdesign; for example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Definition 4.1}\quad
The function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is said to be \textbf{\boldmath
differentiable at $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$} if
\[ f'(z_0 \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \]
exists, i.e., if there exists a complex number, denoted $f'(z_0)$, such that
\[ \left| f(z) - f(z_0) - f'(z_0) \times (z-z_0) \right|
    = o(z-z_0) \quad [z\to z_0]. \]
\end{document}

